# Alternative to `safe_mode_protected_env_vars` in PHP7?

Tags: php, security, environment-variables, ld-preload

In old PHP installations you could set `safe_mode_protected_env_vars` to prevent users or attackers from setting sensitive environment variables like `LD_PRELOAD`. As `safe_mode` was removed in PHP5.4 this is no longer possible.

Anybody knows how to do it in PHP7? The only option I see is to add `putenv` to `disable_functions` but that seems a bit overkill.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent/protect?

Comment: @Dave I am trying to prevent the use of `LD_PRELOAD` so it cannot be exploited to bypass `open_basedir`

Comment: I don't believe that exploit is possible with the latest versions of PHP. What have you seen that leads you to believe that it may still be possible?

Comment: @Dave I exploited it in PHP7.0. It is possible. Why don't you believe it would be possible?
https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&search_for=open_basedir+bypass&x=0&y=0

Comment: Then I would suggest that you open a bug with the PHP security folks.

Comment: They already know about the security problem. LD_PRELOAD is a common attack verctor.

Comment: You did notice that it does NOT work with the latest version of PHP 7.4.x right? Sounds like updating to the current version will resolve your concern.

Comment: @Dave I apreciate you taking your time to answer, however it looks that you have no clue of what you are talking about so I am wondering why are you answering without or with false information?

Where did you see that this does not happen in PHP 7.4? Where did you get that information?

Comment: If you go to the bug on php.net cited above and follow the link there to https://3v4l.org/75AX0 you will see that version 7.4 does NOT have the issue. It also does not fail with versions 5.3.0 through 5.3.10 but starts failing again at 5.3.11 all of the way through 7.3.8. The link was posted on 2019-05-07 09:48 UTC.

Comment: @Dave the link that I posted above was only to show all the problems that PHP has with `open_basedir` bypass. I am talking specificially about the use of `LD_PRELOAD` to bypass it. In PHP 7.4.2, available in Debian Sid, this method is still efective as I have just confirmed.
There are several other ways of bypassing `open_basedir`, but this one is the one that I need more information to fix.
Thank you for taking your time to answer, but I am afraid you are not understanding the problem here, which is basically how to prevent the use of certain environment variables.